# Rails 3 and clean URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

What is the most efficient way to map URLs to database IDs.

Example:

```
/newspaper/article/how-interesting-is-internet
```

In routing the `newspaper_controller` gets `article` and `how-interesting-is-internet`.

Where and how should I store the mapping for clean URLs and IDs?

Comment: Why not use e.g. the article title as slug? Like this you wouldn't need any kind of mapping, as long as your title/slug is unique across a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FriendlyId is a good plugin for this (https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

It allows you to specify a database column that will be used to create the id (name or description or whatever) and it takes care of making everything just work.

Answer (score 2):

you should check out `to_param` method

```
class Article < AR::Base
  def to_param
    self.cool_url # cool_url is column in your articles table with your clean url
  end
end
```

So my suggestion is to store your clean_url right in your Article model with your ID and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

I like the friendlyId approach too

The way I handle this sort of thing using the clasic blog example

Blog Controller {Fetches all posts by date}
Posts Controller {}

***Routes***

```
resource :blog do
  resources :posts      
end
```

**App/Models/Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :site
    has_friendly_id :title, :use_slug => true   
end
```

Then you end up with some nice paths

```
blog_path #Blog Index
blog_post(p) #Post Show
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to_param method to create custom URLs such as http://myblog.com/posts/2012-04-22/123-my-first-post.html

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "/posts/#{published_at}/{id}-#{title.parameterize}.html"
  end
end
```